# Excel formula to lookup row number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following columns on a spreadsheet

```
1 ITEM  LOCATION  EXISTS?
2 apple    3    
3 banana   6      TRUE
4 fish     9    
5 dog       
6 cherry          TRUE
7 goat      
8 horse     
9 chicken         TRUE
```

The LOCATION column is a list of row numbers pertaining to ITEM.

I'd like the EXISTS column to be marked as TRUE for the row number listed in the LOCATION column.

I'm really stuck and would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried please? It will help to see where you've gotten stuck.

Comment: Your question is pretty ambiguous about the Exists column.  Exactly what are you evaluating and where to determine whether it's true?

Comment: Yes I'm sorry about that, I was really struggling to get my head around the problem so articulating it into a logical question was really tough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,ROW())>0
```

To always return TRUE or FALSE, or

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,ROW())>0,TRUE,"")
```

To only return when TRUE and leave blank when FALSE.

How it works:

`ROW()` is what returns the current row number.

`COUNTIF` counts how many times the current row number is entered in column `B` (the LOCATION).

`>0` checks if the result of the `COUNTIF` is more than 0 (row number is listed in the location column at least once) and returns TRUE or FALSE. Or you nest your Logical Test in an `IF` function where you can select what the TRUE or FALSE results should be.

Comment: Thank you, that gave me all the information I needed to solve my real world problem.